# fread() optimisation matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, fread

I am reading a 40 MB file with three different ways. But the first one is way faster than the 2 others. Do you guys have an idea why ? I would rather implement condition in loops or whiles to separate data than load everything with the first quick method and separate them then - memory saving -

```
LL=10000000;

fseek(fid,startbytes, 'bof');

%% Read all at once %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
tic
AA(:,1)=int32(fread(fid,LL,'int32'));
toc
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

fseek(fid,startbytes,'bof');

%% Read all using WHILE loop %%%%%%%%%%%%%
tic
i=0;
AA2=int32(zeros(LL,1));
while i<LL
    i=i+1;
    AA2(i,1)=fread(fid,1,'int32');      
end
toc 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

fseek(fid,startbytes,'bof');

%% Read all using FOR loop %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
tic
AA3=int32(zeros(LL,1));
for i=1:LL
    AA3(i,1)=fread(fid,1,'int32');      
end
toc 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Elapsed time is 0.312916 seconds.

Elapsed time is 138.811520 seconds.

Elapsed time is 116.799286 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my two cents on this:

#### Is the JIT accelerator enabled?

Since MATLAB is an interpreted language, `for` loops can be quite slow. `while` loops may be even slower, because the termination condition is re-evaluted in each iteration (unlike `for` loops that iterate a predetermined number of times). Nevertheless, this is not so true with [JIT acceleration](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/news_notes/may03/profiler.html), which can significantly boost their performance.

I'm not near MATLAB at the moment, so I cannot reproduce this scenario myself, but you can check yourself whether you have JIT acceleration turned on by typing the following in the command window:

```
feature accel
```

If the result is `0` it means that it's disabled, and this is probably the reason for the huge reduction in performance.

#### Too many system calls?

I'm not familiar with the internals of `fread`, but I can only assume that one `fread` call to read the entire file invokes less [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) than multiple `fread` calls. System calls are usually expensive, so this can, to some extent, account for the slowdown.

Comment: @user1245845  you've got me stumped... when time allows, I'll try to do some testing and get back to you on this.